# MySQL group by number series

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just starting to learn MySQL and I have encountered this problem which I badly needed the solution or just the logic.

For example I have this table:

```
id         a 
--        --
 1         1
 2         2
 3         3
 4         5
 5         6
 6         7
 7         9
 8        10
 9        11
10        12
```

Now, what I want is to display all the data in column `a` which should be grouped by series. In this case the result should be:

```
series_start|series_end|count
------------+----------+-----
           1          3     3
           5          7     3
           9         12     4
```

This needs a lot of subqueries and joins. I just can't figure it out by now.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: It needs several JOINs, but no subqueries ;-)

Comment: SELECT a.a start
     , MIN(c.a) end
     , MIN(c.a) - a.a + 1 diff
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON a.a = b.a + 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.a >= a.a
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table d 
    ON d.a = c.a+1
 WHERE b.a IS NULL 
   AND c.a IS NOT NULL
   AND d.a IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.a;

Answer (score 2):

This is a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem, and here's another method of solving it, which also uses variables:

```
SELECT
  MIN(a) AS series_start,
  MAX(a) AS series_end,
  MAX(a) - MIN(a) + 1 AS series_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    a,
    @r := @r + 1 AS r
  FROM
    yourtable,
    (SELECT @r := 0) AS x
  ORDER BY
    a
) s
GROUP BY
  a - r
ORDER BY
  a - r
;
```

This is how it works.

The subquery assigns row numbers to the table rows and returns this row set:

```
 a   r
--  --
 1   1
 2   2
 3   3
 5   4
 6   5
 7   6
 9   7
10   8
11   9
12  10
```

In this case the `r` column, which stores the row numbers, happens to match the `id` column in your data sample, but I'm assuming that in general the `id` column may have gaps, and for that reason it cannot be used here.

The main query groups the results by the difference between `r` and `a`: for sequential values, it will always be the same:

```
 a   r  a - r
--  --  -----
 1   1      0
 2   2      0
 3   3      0
 5   4      1
 6   5      1
 7   6      1
 9   7      2
10   8      2
11   9      2
12  10      2
```

and that allows us to group such rows together. All that remains at this point is to get the minimim, maximum and count, which gives you this output:

```
series_start  series_end  series_count
------------  ----------  ------------
           1           3             3
           5           7             3
           9          12             4
```

A SQL Fiddle demonstration of this query, for which I've borrowed @sgeddes's schema, can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05484/3).

---

**UPDATE**

As numeric variables cannot be used (according to comments), you could assign row numbers using a triangular self-join, but it will be much less efficient than using a variable. Anyway, here's the modified version, changes to the previous query being highlighted in bold:

```
SELECT
  MIN(a) AS series_start,
  MAX(a) AS series_end,
  MAX(a) - MIN(a) + 1 AS series_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    data.a,
    COUNT(*) AS r
  FROM
    yourtable AS data
  INNER JOIN
    yourtable AS tally
  ON
    data.id >= tally.id
  GROUP BY
    data.a
) s
GROUP BY
  a - r
ORDER BY
  a - r
;
```

The approach itself remains unchanged: the subquery returns a ranked row set, which is then processed same as previously.

A SQL Fiddle demo for the modified query is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05484/5).

Comment: O.O I can't use the method above. Our company is using a CGI which treats any word that stars with '@' as a variable and is treated as a normal string which will be concatinated to the statement itself. Without an initial value, it will be left as blank causing an error.

Comment: The `@r` is indeed a variable in this context, but I don't really understand what you are saying about how your CGI treats a word starting with a `@`. Does it treat it as a variable or as a string, after all? Anyway, if it's only the `(SELECT @r := 0)` subquery that is the issue, you could try removing it and replacing the `@r := @r + 1 AS r` with `@r := IFNULL(@r, 0) + 1 AS r`.

Comment: Any word that starts with an '@' is treated as a variable(of string type). I could not use also the := to assign values, it causes an error.

Comment: @Tuyhakaw: Ah, I see now. Please see my update for an alternative version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using `user defined variables`:

```
select min(series_start) series_start, 
  max(series_end) series_end,
  1 + max(series_end) - min(series_start) count
from (
  select t1.a series_start, 
    t2.a series_end,
    @val:=IF(@prev=t2.a-1,@val,@val+1) val,
    @prev:=t2.a
  from yourtable t1
    join yourtable t2 on t1.a = t2.a-1
    join (select @val:= 0, @prev:= 0) t
  order by t2.a
  ) t
group by val
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05484/1)

Comment: It's working fine, but I need to read more to understand fully this  user defined variables method. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @Tuyhakaw -- no worries, glad I could help!  Basically the `val` variable keeps track of sequential records.  Grouping by that variable, you can use aggregate functions to achieve your results.  Best regards.

Comment: By the way I have additional question: What does a simple `join` do to tables? I know about `left`,`right` and other `joins` but not this one.

Comment: @Tuyhakaw -- using `join` by itself is like saying `inner join` -- it's just a shorthand.  Here's a good article on the different types of joins (inner vs. outer): http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: O.O I can't use the method above. Our company is using a CGI which treats any word that stars with '@' as a variable and is treated as a normal string which will be concatinated to the statement itself. Without an initial value, it will be left as blank causing an error.